# Setting stroke-width to 0 compatible with Android browser

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to set the width of a stroke to 0 using the following style:

```
.link {                                                                                                               
   stroke: #6E6E6E;                                                                                                    
   stroke-width: 0px;                                                                                                  
}
```

This works just fine in Chrome, Safari, and the mobile version of Chrome on Android.  However, it does not work in the Android Mobile browser (the default browser).  The stroke width comes out as 1px instead of 0px.  I have tried *-webkit-stroke-width: 0px;* but that also does not solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried it without the unit (eg. `stroke-width: 0`)?

Comment: make sure you have compatible ver: http://caniuse.com/text-stroke

Comment: Why do you want use a stroke width of 0px, instead of "stroke:none"?

Comment: @Riskbreaker the question is about stroke-width for SVG (see tags), not about text-stroke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this bug in an older version of Chrome, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15461

Two solutions to try: `stroke: none` or `stroke-width: 0.000001`

Comment: thanks bud, that worked! will accept as answer when it is possible to